# How can I convert seconds in a dataframe column to hms format?

Tags: r

I tried this code but it returns NA values:

```
a %>% 
  mutate(hms=seconds_to_period("duration"))
```

I had obtained "duration" in seconds by subtracting start_date and end_date in the dataframe.

Comment: Welcome. Please share a reproducible example of your data using ``dput(a)`` - it'll make it much easier for others to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Try without the quotation.

Comment: Please refer [this websit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to post a reproducible example.